# Split number into rows so that they sum up to the original number

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-server-2012

I have a table [tbl] with money values

```
id   mon
1    10.17
2    36.00
```

I need to split these values into rows by a set of specific ranges [1.00,10.00,25.00]. The sum of the new values grouped by id will equal the original value.

```
id   mon    sum
1    1.00   1.00
1    9.17   10.17
2    1.00   1.00
2    10.00  11.00
2    25.00  36.00
```

Is there any way to do this without using a cursor?

Comment: There should be a way using Ranking/Analytic functions. Which version of SQL Version you're using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: So the specific values can only be there once? For example 100 would be 25 + 10 + 1 + 64?

Comment: that is correct.  the sum of the rows created should equal the original value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
;with CTE as (select t2.value, t1.id, sum(t2.value)
  over (partition by t1.id order by t2.value asc) as total 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.mon >= t2.limit
)

select id, value, total from CTE

union all

select t1.id, t1.mon - c.total, t1.mon 
from table1 t1
outer apply (select top 1 id, total from CTE c 
    where c.id = t1.id order by c.value desc) c
where t1.mon > c.total
order by 1,3
```

This uses additional table that has the limits stored to join with the original data and then uses running total in a CTE and joins that to the original table to get the remaining amounts

You can test the example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c703b/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt using window functions and `CROSS APPLY`:

```
;WITH Cte(s) AS(
    SELECT CAST(1 AS MONEY) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 25
)
,CteRange AS(
    SELECT
        s,
        e = SUM(s) OVER(ORDER BY s)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    t.id,
    mon = CASE WHEN t.mon > x.e THEN x.s ELSE mon - LAG(x.e) OVER(PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY x.s) END,
    [sum] = CASE WHEN t.mon < x.e THEN t.mon ELSE x.e END
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT * FROM CteRange
)x
WHERE t.mon > x.s

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t.id,
    mon = t.mon - x.e,
    [sum] = t.mon
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 e
    FROM CteRange
    ORDER BY e DESC
)x(e)
WHERE t.mon > e
ORDER BY t.id, mon
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b587/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

This works for your given example data, you just need to predefine ranges all by yourself (I've used `CROSS JOIN VALUES`, but this can be done however you want/prefer). I think that's not an issue. I've used running SUM and analytic functions to achieve that.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY (1, 1)
    , mon MONEY
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (mon)
VALUES (10.17), (36.00);

SELECT id
    , [sum] - SUM(lagRange) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rangeId) AS mon
    , [sum]
FROM (
    SELECT id, rangeId
        , LAG(rangeValue, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rangeId) AS lagRange
        , CASE
            WHEN SUM(rangeValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rangeId) > mon THEN mon
            ELSE SUM(rangeValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rangeId)
        END AS [sum]
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES ((1), (1.00)), ((2), (10.00)), ((3), (25.00))) AS T(rangeId, rangeValue)
    WHERE rangeValue <= mon
    ) AS T;
```

Results:

```
id  mon     sum
-----------------
1   1.00    1.00
1   9.17    10.17
2   1.00    1.00
2   10.00   11.00
2   25.00   36.00
```